# cannot find -lwxmsw30u_core and -lwxbase30u in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I am getting error like this. I have searched my `wxwidgets folder\lib\gcc_dll` this particular libraries are not build.  Am i missing something here?

I have used this command to build `wxwidgets`:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `MONOLITHIC=1` for some reason. If this was intentional, you need to link with the single library produced in this case and not the separate `core` and `base` libraries. If it wasn't, then you should remove the build directories (`build\msw\gcc_mswu` and `lib\gcc_dll`) and rebuild without using it.

Comment: OR you can select `wxWidgets is built as a monolithic library` shown in the options window in a step when creating a project, so it's using the single library for compilation that was produced when building wxWidgets.